# Using datalist input with classname

Tags: html, css, datalist

Is it possible to use datalist input with classname somehow?

```
<input list="browsers" class="browser">

<datalist class="browsers">
  <option value="Edge">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
</datalist>
```

Comment: No, the `class` attribute is to link css style rules to an HTML element. The `list` attribute is to link an input with a datalist.  HOWEVER, you could use javascript to find an element via class and then make the `list` attribute connection that way.

Comment: What you try to achieve?